# Hide/show navigationbar and tabbar onclick

Tags: iphone

HI all,

u all must have notices in iphone photo gallery, wen u open pic, the tabbar and navigation bar do some hide and show functionality.
wen we tap, both appears and after sometime, they get disaapaer..

I want to do exactlly like that, how can i do it???
wen user taps, both gets appear and after a dealy of say 5 sec, they get disaapear.

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is toolbar not tabbar.
**in .h file**

```
IBoulet UINavigationController *navigationController;

IBoulet UIToolBar *toolbar;
```

**connect IBoulet in in XIB**

**in .m file**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    [navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

    toolbar.hidden = TRUE;

}


- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
   UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if (touch.tapCount == 2) {

             [navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
             toolbar.hidden = FALSE;

             [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0) target:self   selector:@selector(hideBar) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    }

 }

 - (void)hidebar 
  {    
    [navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

    toolbar.hidden = TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.....i did everything u mentioned

but on first time only, on double tap, both gets hide and after some delay app gets crashed.....
"*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DetailViewController hideBar]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b28c20'
"

Answer (score 1):

If you're using priyanka's code, the `toolbar.hidden = TRUE` (all caps!) and fix that everywhere else as well.

The accepted values for a BOOL are YES, NO, TRUE, FALSE, 0, and 1.